# How to input data from center of input field and not the left side?

Tags: html, css

How do you get the cursor to show in the middle and fill the information in from the middle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full HTML and CSS answer is:

```html
<input style='text-align: center; width: 300px;' placeholder='You Can Enter Text From The Center'>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can center align the text of an input element with the following CSS:

`input{text-align:center;}`

Comment: Thank you didnt realize it was literally this simple!